# How to make a Silverlight control that can be dragged and clicked?

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, click

I have a user control which can be reduced to a small icon (e.g. a small rectangle).
Then I want that icon to be draggable and I also want my control to be maximized if I click on the icon.

I tried several things and if I use a `Border` for my icon, I can drag-and-drop it, through the events `MouseLeftButtonDown`, `MouseLeftButtonUp` and `MouseMove`. But I lose the `Command` feature and I can't detect a simple click on the border object.

Then I tried to use a `Button` for my icon. This allows me to use the `Command` pattern but I can't drag-and-drop my icon anymore since the event `MouseLeftButtonDown` is not fired.

Any idea on how to achieve this result would be appreciated!

Comment: How will you tell between a user clicking to drag vs clicking to maximize?

Comment: That's why I'm here. To get some hints. I thought about some "timing check". Like a mouse down immediately followed by a mouse up would be interpreted as a click and a longer mouse down would fire the dragging behavior. Would it be the right way?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that.  Different users will click for different amounts of time.  I'd say a single click should allow drag, and double click would maximize.  Unfortunately, Silverlight 4 does not have double click.  I would rethink this design requirement.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about the single & double click and came to the same conclusion. So I'm going to figure out a new way to handle this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got something to work thanks to this similar question: [Draggable AND clickable pushpin in silverlight bing map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712470/draggable-and-clickable-pushpin-in-silverlight-bing-map)

For short, I created a templated control (called `DraggableButton`) which inherits from `Button`. Then I overrode `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` and `OnMouseLeftButtonUp` to cancel the regular behavior.

Now I have a little square that I can move and that supports double click.
I know it might not be very user-friendly but until I find another way, it's OK.